# using select statement in java database

Tags: java, database, select, jdbc, where-clause

I' m trying to get a specific data using the select where statement.I have a database that works fine. What i ve done till now is this

```
while (rs.next()){

            String username2=rs.getString("username");
            if(puname.equals(username2)) {
                System.out.println(puname);
                String queryPass= "select password from userdata where username="+username2;
                rs2 = st.executeQuery(queryPass);
                String passdb=rs2.getString("password");
                System.out.println("pass"+passdb);
```

end the error that i get is Unknown column 'john' in 'where clause'

Comment: read this: http://xkcd.com/327/ you'll be convinced to use a `PreparedStatement`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the other 2 answers, you're constructing a malformed SQL statement.  This is one reason (but probably the least significant reason since it's fail-fast) that you shouldn't generate SQL this way.

By using a prepared statement:

```
//statement is a global\cached statement
if(statement == null) {
    String sql = "select password from userdata where username=?";
    statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
}
statement.setString(1, "John");
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(selectSQL);
```

The database only has to work out the execution plan for the statement once (which is a costly exercise) and you are immune from SQL injection.

In your example, if I passed the value: `'stu' or 1=1` I would be able to execute the statement:

```
select password from userdata where username='Stu' or 1=1
```

returning all the passwords in your database.

Answer (score 2):

This is your resulting SQL string:

```
select password from userdata where username=John
```

It's not quoted, so the database thinks it's a column name.

You can use a [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html), and place a `?` character where the value should be.  Then you can supply the value with [`setString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setString%28int,%20java.lang.String%29) before executing the query.  Using this technique (bind variables) prevents SQL injection, whereas simply quoting your value directly into the string does not.

Answer (score 1):

One issue I see is:

```
String queryPass= "select password from userdata where username="+username2;
```

should be (When String parameter, put it in single quote):

```
String queryPass= "select password from userdata where username= '"+username2+"'";
```

**Note:** It is advised to use [PreparedStatments](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) instead of plain SQL statements to avoid SQL Injection.